# Let a denote a positive constant. If the area under the curve $y=x\sqrt{2ax-x^2}$ from $x=0$ to $x=a$ is equals to 888, find the value of a

Tags: calculus

How would you integrate $y=x\sqrt{2ax-x^2}?$
So far i've tried an online calculator (desmos) to trial and error the solution to this question out because i cant seem to find a way to integrate this.

basically i've got the idea that we have to find the definite integral of $x\sqrt{2ax-x^2}$ from $0$ to a and equate it to $888$ to solve for $A$.

Comment: The idea you got is itself in the question

Comment: Do you know how to complete the square on that quadratic polynomial inside the square root? That would be my first step

Comment: Do you mean $y=x\sqrt{2ax-x^2}$ or $y=x\sqrt{2ax}-x^2$?

Comment: @gimusi the prior

Comment: @imranfat what do i do after? i managed to get   y = x * sqrt(a^2 - (x - a)^2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subsitute $x=2a\sin^2 \theta$

$dx=4a \sin \theta \cos \theta \ d\theta$

Now replace every x and dx

$√2ax-x^2 =√x(2a-x)= √sin\theta(4a^2-4a^2sin^2 \theta)$

We get $\int 2a\sin^2 \theta (2a \sin\theta \cos\theta)4a \sin\theta\cos\theta 
\text{  }d\theta =\\\\ 16a^3\int \sin^4\theta \cos^2 d\theta$

Now i think you can solve it

Comment: Do i just integrate by parts from then on?

Comment: It would be a very intricate process if you use integration by parts and you would be more prone of making mistakes.It would be better if u use trig identities ($sin^2 x=\frac {1-cos (2x)}{2}$ and $cos^2 x=\frac{cos(2x)-1}{2}$.

Comment: Then does the limit changes? Like from 0 to A.

Comment: I don't understand Ur question

Comment: I'm trying to find the definate integral of that function from 0 to A in the original question

Comment: After taking out the indefinite integral put ur limits

Comment: How did you get to this ∫2asin2θ(2asinθcosθ)4asinθcosθ dθ?

Comment: Do you know how to integrate using subsitution ??

Comment: i meant how did you get from $ \sqrt {2ax - x^2} $ to $ 2a sin\theta cos\theta $

Comment: I replaced x by $2asin^2 \theta$ and $dx by 4a sin \theta cos \theta$

Comment: Yes i understand that part but i cant seem to get the sqaure root expression to change to 2a sin(theta)cos(theta)

Comment: Now check the the answer

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Harshit Gupta's formula, you can make life easier since
$$\sin ^4(t) \cos ^2(t)=\sin ^4(t)-\sin ^6(t)$$Using multiple angle formulae (see [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/expansions-of-certain-trigonometric-functions/)), then
$$\sin ^4(t) \cos ^2(t)=-\frac{1}{32} \cos (2 t)-\frac{1}{16} \cos (4 t)+\frac{1}{32} \cos (6t)+\frac{1}{16}$$ which makes the integral quite simple.

Now, for your bounds $x=0 \implies t=0$ and $x=a \implies t=\frac \pi 4$.

So, a quite simple formula.

Comment: @CSY the above explains also why it is important to have a lot of Standard integrals "ready", like higher powers of sine and cosine. You anti derive those once for exercise sake, and then you keep those with your "files".